# Webpack bundle ENOENT: no such file or directory fs.readdirSync

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-2

We would like to create micro apps that run on AWS Lambda. We are investigating webpack 2 for this. However, we have legacy code that uses `fs.readdirSync` to get a list of file/module names to generate a module list. When executing the bundle we get an error `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/innerLib'` because webpack does not know to execute `fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'innerLib'));` in file `lib/lib.js` and resolve an array of file names during bundle time.

What approaches can we take with wepback without making major changes to the legacy code. I have included a simple example below and on [github](https://github.com/isurfbecause/webby)

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require( 'path' );
var webpack = require( 'webpack' );

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: ['./index.js'],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  target: 'node',
}
```

**index.js**

```
const  lib = require('./lib/lib.js');

lib.getModuleList((err, modules) => console.log(modules));
```

**lib/lib.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
let moduleList = [];
let list = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'innerLib'));

exports.getModuleList = getModuleList;

function getModuleList(callback) {
  return callback(null, moduleList);
}

list.forEach(filename => {
  moduleList.push({
    name: filename
  });
});
```

**lib/innerLib/a.js**

```
console.log('a lib loaded');
```

**lib/innerLib/b.js**

```
console.log('b lib loaded');
```

Comment: how are you executing the bundle?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is that `__dirname` is resolving to `/`. To get it to work with webpack, set:

```
node: {
  __dirname: true
}
```

in your webpack.config.js. After adding that, your bundle executes fine for me.