How can i fix the helvetica error in NextJS with pdfkit-Table
Im trying to generate a pdf but everytime it says
⨯ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\HECTOR\Documents.next\server\vendor-chunks/data/Helvetica.afm'
errno: -4058,
syscall: 'open',
code: 'ENOENT',
this is the code
  const imagePath = `./test-results/${testCase.title}_${testCase.reportDate}.jpg`;
    let doc = new PDFDocument();
    doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./test_results/REPORT_${testCase.title}_${testCase.reportDate}.pdf`));
    const tableArray = {
        headers: ["Country", "Conversion rate", "Trend"],
        rows: [
            ["Switzerland", "12%", "+1.12%"],
            ["France", "67%", "-0.98%"],
            ["England", "33%", "+4.44%"],
        ],
    };
    doc.table(tableArray, { width: 300 }); // A4 595.28 x 841.89 (portrait) (about width sizes)
    // move to down
    doc.moveDown();
    // Añade la imagen al documento
    doc.image(imagePath, {
        fit: [250, 300],
        align: 'center',
        valign: 'center'
    });
    doc.end();


I couldn't find a proper way to fix it. I just paste the Helvetica.afm file which i s publicly available in my vendor-chunk/data/ directory. Though beware, everytime you restart you development server the file gets deleted automatically.
But once you build your project, you will have to put it just once, and you wont face this problem persistently.
But please do let me know if you have been able to solve it anyhow, would appreciate a proper fix.

base of https://stackoverflow.com/a/40776082/13200808
add this code to next.config.js


  webpack: (config) => {
    config.node = {
      __dirname: true,
    };
    return config;
  },



